# How to group consecutive timestamps in an SQL table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an SQL table in SQL Server with timestamps that looks like this:

```
  │ Timestamps
──┼────────────────────
1 │ 2022-09-23 15:01:00
2 │ 2022-09-23 15:02:00
3 │ 2022-10-03 14:52:00
4 │ 2022-10-03 14:53:00
5 │ 2022-10-03 14:54:00
6 │ 2022-10-03 14:56:00
7 │ 2022-10-03 14:57:00
8 │ 2022-10-03 14:58:00
9 │ 2022-10-03 14:59:00
```

I want to extract all consecutive date ranges from the table, where the difference between each timestamp in the range is only one minute. This is the desired result:

```
  │ From                │ To
──┼─────────────────────┼─────────────────────
1 │ 2022-09-23 15:01:00 │ 2022-09-23 15:02:00
2 │ 2022-10-03 14:52:00 │ 2022-10-03 14:54:00
3 │ 2022-10-03 14:56:00 │ 2022-10-03 14:59:00
```

Note that e.g. rows 3, 4 and 5 are grouped into one row, because the timestamps `2022-10-03 14:52`, `2022-10-03 14:53` and `2022-10-03 14:54` are consecutive. The remaining timestamps from `2022-10-03 14:56` to `2022-10-03 14:59` get grouped into its own range, because there is a gap between the ranges (where `2022-10-03 14:55` would have been).

What is an SQL query that achieves this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a classic Gaps-and-Islands.

**Example**

```
Select TS1 = min([timestamps])
      ,TS2 = max([timestamps])
 From ( 
        Select *
              ,Grp = row_number() over( order by [timestamps])
                   - datediff(minute,0,[timestamps])
         From YourTable
      ) A
 Group By Grp
```

**Results**

```
TS1                         TS2
2022-10-03 14:56:00.000     2022-10-03 14:59:00.000
2022-10-03 14:52:00.000     2022-10-03 14:54:00.000
2022-09-23 15:01:00.000     2022-09-23 15:02:00.000
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Nice and tidy solution!  

Answer (score 3):

This is a `gaps and islands` issue,

Using the first `cte` to find differences between consecutive rows using the window function `LEAD()` and the second `cte` to find the group id for each consecutives rows:

```
with cte as (
    select *, lead(Timestamps) over (order by Timestamps) as lead,
              case when 
              datediff(mi, Timestamps, LEAD(Timestamps) over (order by Timestamps)) = 1 then 0 else 1 end as diff
    from mytable
),
cte2 as (
  select *, sum(diff) over(order by Timestamps) as grp
  from cte
)
select grp+1 as range_id, min(Timestamps) as [From], max(lead) as [To]
from cte2
where lead is not null
group by grp
```

Result :

```
range_id    From                    To
1           2022-09-23 15:01:00.000 2022-09-23 15:02:00.000
2           2022-09-23 15:02:00.000 2022-10-03 14:54:00.000
3           2022-10-03 14:54:00.000 2022-10-03 14:59:00.000
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/6emk1jx3)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use *sessionization* for that, I find that more readable: Create a new session id as soon as the gap between two timestamps is not 1 min. A two-step query, with a counter set to 1 every time it's not one minute, and a query around it that gets the running sum of that counter:

```
WITH
-- your input ...
indata(id,ts) AS (
          SELECT 1,{ts '2022-09-23 15:01:00'}
UNION ALL SELECT 2,{ts '2022-09-23 15:02:00'}
UNION ALL SELECT 3,{ts '2022-10-03 14:52:00'}
UNION ALL SELECT 4,{ts '2022-10-03 14:53:00'}
UNION ALL SELECT 5,{ts '2022-10-03 14:54:00'}
UNION ALL SELECT 6,{ts '2022-10-03 14:56:00'}
UNION ALL SELECT 7,{ts '2022-10-03 14:57:00'}
UNION ALL SELECT 8,{ts '2022-10-03 14:58:00'}
UNION ALL SELECT 9,{ts '2022-10-03 14:59:00'}
)
-- real query starts here - replace following comma with "WITH" 
,
-- sessionization part 1: counter at 1 if gap > 1 min
sess1 AS (
  SELECT
   *   
  ,CASE
     WHEN DATEDIFF(minute,LAG(ts) OVER(ORDER BY ts), ts) = 1 THEN 0
     ELSE 1
   END AS counter
  FROM indata
)
,
-- get the running sum of the obtained counter above to get a session id
sess2 AS (
  SELECT
    id
  , ts
  , SUM(counter) OVER(ORDER BY ts) AS session_id
  FROM sess1
)
SELECT 
  session_id
, MIN(ts) AS from_ts
, MAX(ts) AS to_ts
FROM sess2
GROUP BY session_id
ORDER BY 1
```

| session_id | from_ts | to_ts |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-09-23 15:01:00.000 | 2022-09-23 15:02:00.000 |
| 2 | 2022-10-03 14:52:00.000 | 2022-10-03 14:54:00.000 |
| 3 | 2022-10-03 14:56:00.000 | 2022-10-03 14:59:00.000 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Bkx7yKHe)

Comment: This is pretty much identical to the other answer on here.